# I am writing a query in snowflake to get data from different tables and views and then want to combine the output in one view so others can access it

Tags: sql, join, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sales AS
SELECT
    PRODUCT_SKU,
    sum(GROSS_SALES - GROSS_RETURNS - COUPON_DISCOUNT) total_sales_ttm,
    sum(GROSS_MARGIN) as gross_margin_ttm,
    avg(COST_OF_GOODS_SOLD - COST_OF_RETURNS) as avg_cost_ttm,
    sum(QUANTITY_SOLD - QUANTITY_RETURNED) as unit_sold_ttm
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE
TRAN_DATE BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE -365) AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY 1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE q_sales AS
SELECT 
    PRODUCT_SKU,
    sum(GROSS_SALES_AMOUNT - GROSS_RETURNS_AMOUNT) q_total_sales_ttm,
    sum(GROSS_MARGIN) as q_gross_margin_ttm,
    avg(COST_OF_GOODS_SOLD - COST_OF_RETURNS) as q_avg_cost_ttm,
    sum(QUANTITY_SOLD - QUANTITY_RETURNED) as q_unit_sold_ttm
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE
TRAN_DATE BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE -365) AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY 1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE prices AS
SELECT 
    rp.SKU, 
    rp.PRICE AS RETAIL_PRICE,
    bp.PRICE AS BASELINE_PRICE
FROM TABLE3 rp
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 bp 
ON rp.SKU=bp.SKU
WHERE
rp.history=1 AND bp.history=1;
```

//Combining temp tables into one query

```
SELECT
    sales.PRODUCT_SKU, 
    total_sales_ttm, gross_margin_ttm, avg_cost_ttm,
    q_total_sales_ttm, q_gross_margin_ttm, q_avg_cost_ttm,
    retail_price,baseline_price
FROM
sales
LEFT JOIN q_sales
ON sales.PRODUCT_SKU = q_sales.PRODUCT_SKU
LEFT JOIN prices
ON sales.PRODUCT_SKU=prices.SKU
```

Comment: so what is the question? And if you want other people to be able to read those tables they will have to not be temporary, as those are scoped to just this session that creates them. perhaps you are wanting transient tables?

Comment: I can create transient tables, but how do I combine the whole query in a final VIEIW , which i can create in DB and share with others

Comment: and what do you mean by "combine"? do you want each tables columns on one column, which will require joins, or do you want the X rows from table1 then the Y rows from table2....

Comment: I mean how do I create a new VIEW with this query and that view will be shared with other folks. Right now this query i wrote in snowflake worksheet - i can run as it is and gets out put - hope I am making sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I make some test data tables:

```
CREATE TABLE sales AS
SELECT
    1 as PRODUCT_SKU,
    10 as total_sales_ttm,
    11 as gross_margin_ttm,
    5 as avg_cost_ttm,
    4 as unit_sold_ttm
;

CREATE TABLE q_sales AS
SELECT 
    1 as PRODUCT_SKU,
    12 as q_total_sales_ttm,
    13 as q_gross_margin_ttm,
    14 as q_avg_cost_ttm,
    15 as q_unit_sold_ttm
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE prices AS
SELECT 
    1 as SKU, 
    42 AS RETAIL_PRICE,
    43 AS BASELINE_PRICE
```

your select:

```
SELECT
    sales.PRODUCT_SKU, 
    total_sales_ttm, gross_margin_ttm, avg_cost_ttm,
    q_total_sales_ttm, q_gross_margin_ttm, q_avg_cost_ttm,
    retail_price,baseline_price
FROM
sales
LEFT JOIN q_sales
ON sales.PRODUCT_SKU = q_sales.PRODUCT_SKU
LEFT JOIN prices
ON sales.PRODUCT_SKU=prices.SKU;
```

gives:

| PRODUCT_SKU | TOTAL_SALES_TTM | GROSS_MARGIN_TTM | AVG_COST_TTM | Q_TOTAL_SALES_TTM | Q_GROSS_MARGIN_TTM | Q_AVG_COST_TTM | RETAIL_PRICE | BASELINE_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 5 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 42 | 43 |

thus to make a view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name as 
SELECT
    sales.PRODUCT_SKU, 
    total_sales_ttm, gross_margin_ttm, avg_cost_ttm,
    q_total_sales_ttm, q_gross_margin_ttm, q_avg_cost_ttm,
    retail_price,baseline_price
FROM
sales
LEFT JOIN q_sales
ON sales.PRODUCT_SKU = q_sales.PRODUCT_SKU
LEFT JOIN prices
ON sales.PRODUCT_SKU=prices.SKU;
```

thus:

```
select PRODUCT_SKU, TOTAL_SALES_TTM, GROSS_MARGIN_TTM from view_name;
```

gives:

| PRODUCT_SKU | TOTAL_SALES_TTM | GROSS_MARGIN_TTM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 |

You will need to make sure the other users have permission to the database/schema where the view is, and give the permissions to run the view, and thus the tables also..

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked. I created Transient tables and then created a view - can't vote +1 as i am new to stackoverflow but really appreciate your help

Comment: You can pick the answer though. That’s more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use transient tables instead of Temporary Tables, as Temporary tables are scoped within a session.

You can then combine these views/tables into a single view and have a Role with SELECT access to the final view, so that users with the role have read-only access to the view.

If you could clarify your ask here further, can help better.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response - can you please explain how do i combine these transient tables into one view - little sample code please - when i tried to create final view it only allows query to start with select